# Tapping / Swiping not detected in Android Studio Google Glass emulator

Tags: java, android, google-glass, gesture

I'm running an emulator for google glass as seen here, works pretty flawlessly by showing settings, main display and even my activity (which I pretend to be an interactive static card).

http://mobilevangelist.com/2014/01/02/gdk-and-the-android-emulator/

I've seen that the motion gestures are captured using ***onKeyUp*** or ***onKeyDown*** events but neither are working and I don't understand why.

Here is my code.

```
public class LiveCardMenuActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override //isn't catching a thing, even with onKeyDown (mouse taps or slides in the emulator)
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keycode, KeyEvent event){
        Log.d("tag","keyUp");
        if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER){
            Log.d("tag","keypadcenter");
            textView.setText("tap");
        }else if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            Log.d("tag","swipedown");
            textView.setText("down");
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
            super.onAttachedToWindow();
            setContentView(R.layout.live_card); 
            //does successfully, I can see the layout in the emulator
           //and I can swipe it to the left (returning to the main display successfully)
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            Log.d("tag","attached to window");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.live_card, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_stop:
                // Stop the service which will unpublish the live card.
                stopService(new Intent(this, LiveCardService.class));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
        super.onOptionsMenuClosed(menu);
        // Nothing else to do, finish the Activity.
        finish();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me on this one? Tyvm!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `setFocusable(true)` on your content view.

Though I don't know much about how this emulator works, this is how you might get this working for standard Android.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `onKeyUp()` when you need to be using `onKeyDown()`. Here's an example I'm using in my Glass project (but I have a physical Google Glass, not using an emulator):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch( keyCode ) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
            Log.e("GESTURE_EVENT", "PostVideoActivity.onKeyDown() TAP/KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER");
            // DO SOMETHING
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            Log.e("GESTURE_EVENT", "PostVideoActivity.onKeyDown() SWIPE/KEYCODE_BACK");
            // DO SOMETHING
            return true;
        default:
            Log.wtf("GESTURE_EVENT", "PostVideoActivity.onKeyDown() DEFAULT -- SHOULDNT BE HERE!");
            return false;
    }
}
```

**edit** Maybe this is an issue with the emulator? I doubt it though but you can test this theory by creating some dummy Android project for a phone/phone emulator that is known to work. If this snippet doesn't even work for the other Android emulation then maybe its something else?